# Echad Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred one?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.

Comment: This is question #1000!

Comment: Elef mi yodeya?

Comment: @Dave, we did that one already: see http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/645 (and http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%A3 )

Comment: @msh210 - Groan... :P

Comment: Anyone have a source for safardim doing 101 on the shofar (a safardi would be a good source)?  How about everyone quoting the 101 yevavos of Sisera's mom (despite that Tos. quotes the Aruch as 100 and who knows how to count any of them!)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learning 101 times is a lot better than learning 100 times

Comment: this was in the list of "100 number" answers: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/3027/meya-mi-yodeya/3031#3031

Answer (score 7):

101 are the bones on each side of the human body. ([Ohalos 1:8](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90_%D7%97))

Answer (score 7):

101 is the total amount in which a unit Terumah [(4:11)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=23509&st=&pgnum=181) and Challah [(1:9)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=23509&st=&pgnum=256)are batel.

Answer (score 3):

101 were the years of [Montefiore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Montefiore).

Comment: According to the linked-to article, he died in his 101st year, before his 101st birthday. You're correct according to רֻבּוֹ כְכֻּלּוֹ, though (and a fortiori according to יום אחד בשנה חשוב שנה). Plus, it fits the beat. :-)

Comment: @msh210 - I notice that you translated Kal Vachomer but not "round to nearest" or "round up."

Comment: I'm used to using the phrase "a fortiori" even in secular contexts, whereas the Hebrew phrases I used refer to halachic concepts only (AFAIK). That said, I'm no ראשון: I'll often pick my words carelessly.

Comment: I've often wondered about this - Outside the philosophy, math (maybe), and classics departments at universities, are secular people you speak to typically familiar with "a fortiori"? (Same question for "ab initio.")

Comment: On second thought, don't answer that yet. It's going to be an actual Question.

Comment: msh210, it does not fit the meter (or beat as you called it). "Montefiore" is properly pronounced "ˌmɒntɪˈfjɔri " See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_of_asteroid_names#M

Comment: @Yahu - my bad. I was assuming otherwise and indeed aiming for the beat.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Did that ever get asked?

Comment: @DoubleAA, [Yes.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3414/are-these-latin-greek-translations-of-hebrew-terms-useful)

Answer (score 2):

this is a phone number of מגן דוד אדום in Israel

Answer (score 1):

One hundred and one are the verses in Parashas Tetzaveh, which corresponds to learning something one hundred and one times. Learning this many times will ensure that you don't forget. Thus, this parasha is often the parasha connected to Parashas Zachor, which exhorts us לא תשכח, do not forget. Amalek, who wants us to forget, is עמל-ק, work up to only 100.

(Heard from R' Nochum Lansky of Ner Israel)