# Are these Latin/Greek translations of Hebrew terms useful?

Tags: words, gentiles

If you use the following Latin or Greek translations of Hebrew terms in conversation with secular people, do they tend to know what you're talking about? If so, in what contexts - a university Classics or Philosophy department, the corner grocery, the accounting firm where you work?

Related: In what secular contexts have you heard other people use these terms?

Examples:

- "[A fortiori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_fortiori_argument)" for "[kal vachomer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmudical_Hermeneutics#Kal_va-Chomer_.28.D7.A7.D7.9C_.D7.95.D7.97.D7.95.D7.9E.D7.A8.29)"
- "[Ab initio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ab_initio)" for "[lechatchila](http://www.judaicasavings.com/Pages/Mehudar)"
- "[Phylacteries](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/phylactery)" for "[tefillin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tefillin)"

Feel free to add more examples, including by editing this question.

Comment: *prima facie* in latin is as *lichorah* in hebrew

Answer (score 1):

Some law professors and judges like using 'a fortiori' and 'ab initio' a lot.

Comment: Juxtapostion is used as well

Answer (score 0):

If you are the Chief of Police of Philadelphia then [*olfacteries*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qdw8gG9EwRs&NR=1&feature=fvwp) for *tefillin* is a very important word! ;-}