# Shemona Ve'esrim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred twenty-eight?

### ?שמונה ועשרים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 328? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 328, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Forget about answering with lazy gematria or with statistical lies.

Comment: I'm not upvoting until there's a חשך pun.

Comment: @Scimonster, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for your suggested improvement. You might be interested in taking the next step and [suggesting](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) an [edit] for a specific improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! Unfortunately, my puns are even worse than yours, so i'd prefer to let you do it.

Comment: The only סימן in ש"ע I'll never *forget* the number for is שכ"ח -- hilchos *pikuach nefesh* baShabbos ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Imrei Chaim Bamidbar page 122](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47076&st=&pgnum=140) in the name of the Kli Yakar on the Pasuk in Devarim 4:9

רַק הִשָּׁמֶר לְךָ וּשְׁמֹר נַפְשְׁךָ מְאֹד, פֶּן-תִּשְׁכַּח אֶת-הַדְּבָרִים אֲשֶׁר-רָאוּ עֵינֶיךָ וּפֶן-יָסוּרוּ מִלְּבָבְךָ, כֹּל, יְמֵי חַיֶּיךָ; וְהוֹדַעְתָּם לְבָנֶיךָ, וְלִבְנֵי בָנֶיךָ

says that the word Zachor / to remember = 227. The word Shachach / to forget = 328. The difference is 101. Therefore one who learns 101 times does not forget.

Comment: Doesn't this belong at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3354/759

Answer (score 7):

[Nechemia 7:22](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt35b07.htm)

> כב  בְּנֵי חָשֻׁם, שְׁלֹשׁ מֵאוֹת עֶשְׂרִים וּשְׁמֹנָה. The children
>   of Hashum, three hundred twenty and eight.